# How to translate this statement into $A \land B$?

Tags: logic

A friend of mine showed me an SAT question today in which one of the choices is:

> No genetic variations that were common to those finches that used technique Q were not common to the finches that did not use technique Q.

I just learned a bit about logic so I tried breaking down the statement into its logical form. I figured the choice is in the form: *It is not true that if A, then not B.*

$$\neg(A,\; then \; \neg B)$$

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
A & B & \neg B & A \rightarrow \neg B & \neg (A \rightarrow \neg B) \\
\hline
T & T & F & F & T \\
T & F & T & T & F \\
F & T & F & T & F \\
F & F & T & T & F \\
\end{array}

This looks like the truth table for *A and B*.

$$A \land B$$

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
A & B & \neg (A \rightarrow \neg B) \\
\hline
T & T & T \\
T & F & F \\
F & T & F \\
F & F & F\\
\end{array}

In the language of $\neg(A,\; then \; \neg B),$ the original statement could be written as:

> It is not true that if a genetic variation is common to the finches that used technique Q, it is not common to the finches that did not use technique Q.

However, I struggled to translate the original statement into the language of "*A and B.*" It doesn't seem to make sense to me to say:

> A genetic variation is common to both the finches that used technique Q and the finches that did not use technique Q.

A genetic variation seems to be a conditional element and we don’t know yet whether it belongs to any specific sets, but the above statement seems to suggest any genetic variation belongs to both sets.

Did I make any mistake? If my analysis is correct, please advise me on how to properly translate the original statement to the language of "*A and B*."

Thank you!

Comment: Quite convoluted... "There is **no** genetic variations that [(were common to those finches that used technique Q) **and** (were **not** common to the finches that did not use technique Q)]".

Comment: $\neg (A \rightarrow \neg B)$ is, by definition of the implication,
equivalent to $\neg (\neg A \lor \neg B)$, which is, by De Morgan's
laws, equivalent to $A \land B$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks! Is there any other interpretation that doesn't involve 2 not's? I.e. Is there any equivalent A and B statement where A and B are not negative statements?

Comment: @Loic Hi, thanks for the insight! That's an interesting point indeed! However, my main concern was how to interpret the original statement (the one about genetic variations) in the language of A and B. Hope to hear your thoughts on that! Thanks!

Comment: "No genetic variations that  were not common to the finches that did not use technique Q" is "there is **no** genetic variation such that **not** ... " i.e. "**every** genetic variation is common to the finches that did not use technique Q".

Comment: To understand how such a convoluted phase would arise: the researchers noticed a difference in behavior between two populations of finches, and wondered if the behavior had a genetic component, or was strictly learned. So they looked for a genetic marker common in the first group, but not in the second. However, the statement says no such marker was found.